# Does Sitecore use Fast Query automatically?

Tags: sitecore

According to Sitecore Data Definition Reference, version 6.4, section 4.3.1:

> Sitecore processes queries using the
>   fasted technology possible. This could
>   be either the SQL database, if the
>   data provider supports the requested
>   query, or in the Sitecore data
>   manager.

If this is so, is there any benefit to using the "fast:" syntax? With what release did automatic technology selection get introduced?

**Update**
I think I figured it out.  Reqular Sitecore queries can only use SQL Server if they do not have predicates.  Fast Query allows simple predicates (e.g. *[@somefield='somevalue']) while still making use of SQL Server.

From **Sitecore CMS 6.4 Data Definition Reference (Section 4.3.4):**

> The SQL Server data provider does not
>   support predicates (the portion of the
>   search string enclosed in square
>   brackets: [@IsHidden != '1']).

From **Sitecore CMS 6 Using Sitecore Fast Query (Section 4.2):**

> This section describes the predicates
>   that are available in Sitecore Fast
>   Query. Predicates are
>    always embedded in square brackets.

```
Example: fast:/sitecore/content/Home/*[@Title = 'Welcome to Sitecore']
```

> Result: returns the items that have the value of the 'Title' field set to 'Welcome to Sitecore'. The 
>   search is performed in the children of the Home Item.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several different approaches to querying items from Sitecore:

- Sitecore Query
- Fast Query
- Lucene

Each approach has its own pros and cons. For example, Sitecore Query and Fast Query both have a limit to the number of items they can return. This limit is the `Query.MaxItems` setting in the `web.config`. Lucene on the other hand is its own beast and uses search indexes stored on disk to access items.

Sitecore query is the most flexible in terms of filtering items right in the query, however the more complex your query is, the longer it will take to run (that's a generalization). Its often easier to make a more generic query then use .NET to filter it, like LINQ. Fast query goes straight to the database to query and thus has limit on the filtering. It runs faster but you can't be as granular with what you want to check in your query.

Lucene is another approach as it uses search indexes to query content and filter. This requires additional configuration work up front and maintenance of the search index.

This can help you decide which approach to take:

- 100 items or less: Sitecore Query
- 1000 items or less: Fast Query
- 1000+ items: Lucene

I've also previously written blog post on this same topic:

- [Options For Querying Items From Sitecore](http://firebreaksice.com/options-for-querying-items-from-sitecore/)

Comment: Thanks for this information, it's helpful.  The main point I was trying to get at in my question is what optimizations Sitecore does to Sitecore Queries, and how these differ from Fast queries.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by optimizations. Are you talking what the Sitecore API does or what developers at Sitecore do? It boils down to the fact that fast query is faster because it goes right to the database but it offers less features within the querying. Basically, think of it this way: if you have a very generic query that doesn't need to be complex, why bother for Sitecore query if you can make it faster with fast query? For very complex queries you may just need to settle for Sitecore query. Most queries should be covered by fast and large data set queries should use Lucene.

Comment: By optimizations, I mean what the Sitecore API does.  According to the Data Definition Reference, Sitecore processes quries using "the fasted technology possible."   If so, when does Sitecore require "Fast:" to access the database?  I was looking for specifics on when Sitecore can do a database query without the Fast hint, and when it requires it.

Comment: I would also like to add that Query returns items in the order they appear within the content tree, but that this is not the case when using fast query.